# What should TCP/IP do if one computer changed its IP address which we are sending data to?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

What's the standard behavior of TCP/IP protocol stack when a computer which we are sending data to suddenly changed its IP address? When this happens, the ARP table in our system is out of date, but the entry for this IP is not timed out?

Is there a way to discover the new IP-mac mapping or we simply drop the queued data and return an error?

Comment: Are you talking about a TCP connection (or perhaps UDP), or anything at a lower level?

Comment: I mean when a computer have a lot of data sending to another end system in the same local network area and it changed it's IP address, what's the mac address we are adding to ethernet header for remaining packets @bruno

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume a TCP connection between A and B. A's IP address suddenly changes.

From B's point of view, what happens is straightforward: B continues to send its data to A's old IP address. There are two possibilities:

- If A's old IP address is now unused then these packets go nowhere. They are dropped on the floor. B doesn't get any acknowledgements for them. Eventually, B decides that the connection has times out. From B's point of view, this is indistinguishable from the situation where A's network connection disappears altogether or A crashes or the power is turned off, etc...
- If A's old IP address has been claimed by a different machine, say C, then the packets that B is sending to C won't make any sense to C. They don't initiate a new TCP connection (they don't have the `SYN` flags set) and they don't match any existing TCP connection known to C. C will respond with `RST` packets, and B will promptly return a "Connection reset by peer" error on the socket.

Either way, the TCP connection is broken and cannot be recovered. Furthermore, there is absolutely nothing either A or B could do about it. A simply isn't going to be able to receive (or send) any more traffic using its old IP address. It is impossible to achieve any further communication on this TCP connection.

From A's perspective it's a little bit different. After A's IP address is changed it ends up in a situation where it has a socket that is bound to a local IP address and port that doesn't exist on the local system anymore. This is normally not allowed (you can't call `bind()` to bind to an IP address that is not a valid local IP address for the system) but it has come to pass anyway. The TCP/IP standard doesn't say what should be done in this case, but actual behaviour is that A would invalidate the socket immediately and return some kind of error to the application without delay.

In conclusion: A detects the problem and the connection is immediately broken, while it might take some time for B to detect the problem and return an error.

As for the ARP table, I am not sure why you are bringing that up, since that's at a lower layer (the data link layer) and doesn't really have much to do with what happens at the IP (much less TCP) layer. But, yes, the ARP tables of nodes on the same local network as A (such as a local router) now have a stale entry for A's old IP address. They'll gain a new valid entry for A's new IP address soon enough though (the first time they try to send a packet to this IP address) so it's not a problem. The stale entry could cause traffic for the old IP address to be misdirected at A, but if some other node picks up A's old IP address then gratuitous ARPs will take care of that, too.

Finally, the question "Is there a way to discover the new IP-mac mapping or we simply drop the queued data and return an error?" doesn't make sense. Sure there is a way to discover new IP-mac mappings: it's called ARP. That's ARP's sole function. But it has nothing to do with queued data, which is a concept that only has meaning two or more layers up the protocol stack.

In a comment you clarified that you are talking about the case where A and B are on the same local network as each other, but this doesn't make any difference to the answer. It's the same whether A and B are on the same local network or whether they are on remote networks.

Comment: With the assumption that the connection is TCP, node B will detect the change later, but for UDP, there is no response even A didn't change it's IP address, so how does B know it. I mentions ARP because I don't know whether A can send some error message when it received a packet with right ethernet header but wrong IP address? @Celada

Comment: For UDP, B will never know it. It will gladly continue to send datagrams to A's old IP address forever and ever, if that's what the application does.

Comment: No, A will not send an error if it receives a packet that is not addressed to it. If A has IP forwarding enabled (it is configured to act as a router) then it will attempt to route that packet appropriately. If it has IP forwarding disabled (it is configured to act as a host) then it will just assume the packet was misdirected and drop it.